# Cannot deploy to with gh-pages with specific project due to error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages

Keep getting the error:

> error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
>
> fatal: unable to fork

The project builds correctly but when trying to deploy my website it fails.
Website was created with "create-react-app" on my windows 8 pc with the command "gh-pages -d build"

This issue only occurs in this specific project on my pc as when I create a new project with "create-react-app" on my pc it'll deploy fine. This specific project can also be deployed fine with "gh-pages -d build" on my mac but not my pc.

[Error of failing to deploy on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZtqz.jpg)

[Error log console references](https://imgur.com/Nj7bkkS)

[Repository](https://github.com/AnarchySheep/reactSite)

Somewhere along the line I must've messed up something. I've looked over the web, tried reinstalling git, editor, dependencies and am super confused as to what's causing this. It must be an operating system difference? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's trying to spawn `sh.exe` but can't find it.

You need to add the git directory that contains sh.exe to your system variables.

(go start and type: 'path'. This should provide you with a shortcut to 'system environment variables'. If not look up how to [edit environment variables](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) on your version of windows.)

Once you have the environment variables dialogue box open, have a look in the System variables > 'path' list. There may be a git directory there that doesn't contain `sh.exe`. You need to replace it with one that does (ensure this also contains `git.exe`). 
On my pc `sh.exe` was found in:

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin

Once this is done restart the terminal and attempt to deploy again.