# ReactJS: deploy with gh-pages error cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory, unable to fork

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, github-pages

I have been this issue for months. Where, I cannot deploy a react app to GitHub pages. I keeps getting this error, even with any project.

```
error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-recipe-app@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-recipe-app@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51464032/cannot-deploy-to-with-gh-pages-with-specific-project-due-to-error-cannot-spawn) and it makes no difference.

I have been following this [documentation](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages).