# Uploading to git using angular-gh-pages Remote url mismatch

Tags: angular, git, npm, angular-cli

I have updated my project to use an angular workspace and would like to deploy my demo application using angular-gh-pages.  The repo is https://github.com/Gillardo/ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup

I have created a command in package.json called gh-pages which executes the command `ng deploy demo --no-silent` but when i run it i get this error in the console.  Its seems that the project has built successfully, but its failing on uploading it to git?

I am running this on windows 10 machine.

Can anyone help please?

```
‍ Uploading via git, please wait...
Cloning https://github.com/Gillardo/ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup/ into node_modules\gh-pages\.cache\github.com!Gillardo!ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup
Cleaning
Fetching origin
Checking out origin/gh-pages
❌ An error occurred when trying to deploy:
git-upload-pack '.': git-upload-pack: command not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Further to the comments i have run `SET GIT_TRACE=1` in my windows command line and then run the code again, this is what i got

[image: image with gittrace set]

I have done this, after deleting my whole repository, running `npm install` to install my node_modules and then running `npm run gh-pages` which i have setup as a command, and runs this, as in my package.json `"gh-pages": "ng deploy demo --no-silent"`

Not sure if this makes any difference, but in my angular.json file, i have set this

[image]

EDIT:
Here is the text in the picture when it failed

```
�‍� Uploading via git, please wait...
Cloning https://github.com/Gillardo/ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup.git into node_modules\gh-pages\.cache\github.com!Gillardo!ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup.git
❌ An error occurred when trying to deploy:
Remote url mismatch.  Got "12:21:47.470038 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin" but expected "https://github.com/Gillardo/ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup.git" in node_modules\gh-pages\.
cache\github.com!Gillardo!ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup.git.  Try running the `gh-pages-clean` script first.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0 gh-pages: `ng deploy demo --no-silent`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0 gh-pages script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Darren\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-03T11_21_47_564Z-debug.log
```

And here is what was in that log encase that is helpful

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Darren\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'gh-pages' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.0
3 info using node@v10.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'pregh-pages', 'gh-pages', 'postgh-pages' ]
5 info lifecycle ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0~pregh-pages: ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0
6 info lifecycle ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0~gh-pages: ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0~gh-pages: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0~gh-pages: PATH: C:\Users\Darren\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Github\ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup\node_modules\.bin;D:\Github\ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Users\Darren\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Darren\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Darren\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Darren\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Darren\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\Darren\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
9 verbose lifecycle ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0~gh-pages: CWD: D:\Github\ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup
10 silly lifecycle ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0~gh-pages: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ng deploy demo --no-silent' ]
11 silly lifecycle ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0~gh-pages: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0~gh-pages: Failed to exec gh-pages script
13 verbose stack Error: ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0 gh-pages: `ng deploy demo --no-silent`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Darren\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:304:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Darren\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0
15 verbose cwd D:\Github\ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Darren\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "gh-pages"
18 verbose node v10.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.4.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0 gh-pages: `ng deploy demo --no-silent`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0 gh-pages script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

If i run `SET "GIT_TRACE=" before running the command i get this

```
Checking out origin/gh-pages
❌ An error occurred when trying to deploy:
error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0 gh-pages: `ng deploy demo --no-silent`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

And the log says this

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Darren\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'gh-pages' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.0
3 info using node@v10.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'pregh-pages', 'gh-pages', 'postgh-pages' ]
5 info lifecycle ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0~pregh-pages: ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0
6 info lifecycle ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0~gh-pages: ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0~gh-pages: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0~gh-pages: PATH: C:\Users\Darren\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Github\ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup\node_modules\.bin;D:\Github\ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Users\Darren\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Darren\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Darren\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Darren\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Darren\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\Darren\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
9 verbose lifecycle ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0~gh-pages: CWD: D:\Github\ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup
10 silly lifecycle ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0~gh-pages: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ng deploy demo --no-silent' ]
11 silly lifecycle ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0~gh-pages: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0~gh-pages: Failed to exec gh-pages script
13 verbose stack Error: ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0 gh-pages: `ng deploy demo --no-silent`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Darren\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:304:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Darren\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0
15 verbose cwd D:\Github\ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Darren\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "gh-pages"
18 verbose node v10.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.4.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0 gh-pages: `ng deploy demo --no-silent`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup@5.1.0 gh-pages script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: what shell are you using ? can you check if `git-upload-pack` exists as a command from your shell ? try for example to call `git-upload-pack --help`

Comment: For further debugging, run  `set GIT_TRACE=1` if you are using Windows cmd or `export GIT_TRACE=1` if you are using git-bash and then run your git command and update the question with the output of the same

Comment: Thanks for the advice,i have updated my post with what you wanted.

Comment: So you are no longer getting this error : `git-upload-pack '.': git-upload-pack: command not found`?

Comment: sorry yes, getting different error now as above

Comment: Please update the question with the error output as text, as it is not very clear from screenshots.

Comment: updated with text for you, thanks @SaurabhPBhandari

Comment: It looks like debugging itself (by setting `set GIT_TRACE=1`)  is interfering with the process based on this `Got "12:21:47.470038 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin" but expected "https://github.com/Gillardo/ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup.git" `, disable debugging using this `set "GIT_TRACE="` and do you see any change ?

Comment: add output for this in post in text for you.

Comment: Based on the new error : `cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork` in your edit, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51464032/10155936) and [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12138#issuecomment-271071554)

Comment: Your first link fixed the error and it is now working, if you put this in your answer, i will reward you the bounty.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: By the first link if you mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51464032/10155936), I have already added that in the answer, see this line `See Cannot deploy to with gh-pages with specific project due to error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory and cannot spawn sh on Windows for solutions.` in the last section of the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Git version**

Check your `git` version if it follows the [Prerequisites](https://github.com/angular-schule/angular-cli-ghpages#%EF%B8%8F-prerequisites-)

> Git **1.9** or higher (execute `git --version` to check your version)

**Git for Windows is not installed correctly**

Based on your edit which shows this error :

```
❌ An error occurred when trying to deploy:
error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

See [Cannot deploy to with gh-pages with specific project due to error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51464032/10155936) and [cannot spawn sh on Windows](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12138#issuecomment-271071554) for solutions.

Comment: thanks for all your help! Follow the comments above and the lnk in this answer fixed my problem